# Would it be up to code to use electrical box extender behind fridge that bulges out (California)?

Tags: electrical

The fridge outlet uses aluminium wiring that is attached to copper only outlet. So I am thinking of upgrading it to alumiconns. Unfortunately:

1. alumiconn connectors are quite large and don't fit in that small box (I was able to fit 2 alumiconns and a wago for ground as **temporary** hack).
2. the electrical box is new construction (i.e. nailed to studs). So I would prefer to replace the box only as last resort.

Can I simply use electrical box extender? Would it have to be flush with wall or outlet bulging behind fridge is acceptable?

Comment: Is the box metal or plastic?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel metallic

Comment: Are you using the wago lever connector for the ground? Wago does have a joint compound for aluminum wires. I don't think wago  lever connectors are rated for aluminum but would probably work on the ground wires with joint compound.

Comment: How about just using a CO-ALR receptacle?

Answer (score 2):

### Throw the box extender ring on there and roll

Since you have a metal box, the most straightforward thing to do would indeed be to toss the appropriate size extension ring on there and go.  You can also use a surface raceway starter box if you'd prefer, but those aren't available in quite as many sizes.  As to Code compliance? Well, Code doesn't care one whit if your boxes stick out from the wall, and even would let you wire a house entirely with surface-mounted conduit or raceway and surface-mounted boxes to match. Its only concern is that the box is not set back into the wall surface in a way that renders exposed wall surface materials vulnerable to sparks.